# What tools exist for monitoring the CPU and memory utilization of Firefox?

Tags: firefox, memory, monitoring, cpu-usage

Firefox appears to using too much memory and cpu even when it is idle

What tools exist for monitoring the CPU and memory utilization of Firefox?

I am thinking of an equivalent of Sysinternals Process Explorer for Firefox or something like top or htop, on a page, script and addon basis. More technically oriented, something I can see and hand over to the script designers or Mozilla and say "see what this doing to my browsing experience!!"

Comment: To solve my immediate needs I installed the NoScript addon, and I am surprised at how much needless Javascript hampers my browsing experience.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consider using [System Monitor](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/system-monitor/):

> Provides CPU usage and memory usage graphs on the toolbar.

[image]

Comment: I am looking more along the lines of something which gives more detailed info, ie which pages and scripts are causing the problem. I'll add more detail to the question

Comment: There isn't a tool that shows detailed CPU usage since the main issue with FF is high **memory** usage and not CPU usage. Following articles describe tools (usually used by developers) designed for detecting memory leaks:- [Firefox memory leak detection tool](http://www.squarefree.com/2006/01/13/memory-leak-detection-tool/) and [Leak Monitor Extension](http://dbaron.org/mozilla/leak-monitor/) Hope this helps...

Comment: I do get issues where FF will freeze when switching tabs, like it needs to update some data, and won't switch to the tab for a couple seconds. During this switch time it maxes out a single core. I just did a OS wipe recently, and the problem seems to persist. Only thing I brought over was favorites via export/import.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like Mozilla themselves is [looking for such a tool](http://blog.mozilla.com/jorendorff/2009/11/24/wanted-an-extension-for-profiling-firefox/).

The comments on that blog post lead to a few approaches to the problem:

- [Memory Profiler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/memory-profiler/)
- [XUL Profiler](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xul-profiler-by-yoono/)
- [FireBug](http://getfirebug.com/javascript) also contains profiling features

Comment: Memory and XUL Profiler aren't compatible with FF11 and don't seem to have been updated for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `More` > `Task Manager` or typing `about:performance` in the address bar

[image]